# Showing notification in IOS using UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I am working on a conference based application. I want to show an incoming call window to the user, I am using UIActionSheet to show that notification. Now, the problem here is that the call may come at any time from the server, at that we may be in our application any view, how can I show the incoming call notification using UIActionSheet? What delegate I have to set?

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:msg_string
                              delegate:(id)??????????????????
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ACCEPT" 
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"DECLINE" 
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: an object that is guaranteed to be alive; e.g. the application's delegate.  also, in a typical iOS application structure, it has a reference to the top level of the view hierarchy.

Comment: U are talking about root view?

Comment: @alanduncan I have tried with root object, Action sheet was not showed  in my current view, instead my current view is not responding. Any idea?

Comment: try AppDelegate class..use the .window object to present the ActionSheet.

Comment: which iOS platform r u using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an object that is guaranteed to be alive; e.g. the application's delegate. also, in a typical iOS application structure, it has a reference to the top level of the view hierarchy. -Alan

Answer (score 0):

you should set like below.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:msg_string
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ACCEPT" 
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"DECLINE" 
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

delegate is class where to UIActionSheetDelegate method is implemented.

like e.g

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {   // you code         }
@end
```

so clickedButtonAtIndex is actionSheet delegate method which is in viewController Class and you alertView also shown from ViewController Class then you have to set `self`. or if alertView shown from other class and delegate method body written in ViewController class then as delegate you need to set object of ViewController class.